# On spherical distributions in abstract harmonic analysis

Tags: group-theory, functions, reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I need a detailed and comprehensive guidance or possibly relevant materials that can help me in my research on spherical distributions on a locally compact group. Jacques Faraut wrote on spherical distributions on hyperbolic spaces in a famous paper in 1978, " Distributions sphériques sur les espaces hyperboliques..." Helminck A.G.  and Helminck G.F. did the same in 2002 and 2005. However I am still confused as per the true and explicit picture of a spherical distribution in abstract harmonic analysis.

Comment: [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) is a right forum for such questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.